# Different results for IN vs. EXISTS / JOIN - why?

Tags: sql, sqlite

a followup to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393036/nested-select-works-when-using-nonexistant-column-why). **Note this is not a duplicate**, the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824241/sql-replaced-not-in-with-not-exists-and-results-differ) was missing a `WHERE` clause which I have ;) .

I think I have two variants of the same thing, with a sanity check. My problem is - one returns nothing whereas the other one returns what I would expect. My problem is I don't understand why - can somebody help me out here?

Everything is SQLite3.

Variant 1:

```sql
select
    z.license,
    z.username
from
    check_table as z
where
    (
        z.username not in (
            select a.mail_username
            from Address as a 
        )
    )
order by
    license, username;
```

Variant 2:

```sql
select
    z.license,
    z.username
from
    check_table as z
where
    (
        not exists (
            select 1
            from Address as a
            where z.username = a.mail_username
    )
)
order by
    license, username;
```

Sanity check:

```sql
select
    z.username,
    a.mail_username
from
    check_table as z
    left join Address as a
        on z.username = a.mail_username
where
    a.mail_username is null
order by
    mail_username
```

Results:

- Variant 1 returns nothing, but should IMO (0.004 sec)
- Variant 2 returns 265 results (0.097 sec)
- Variant 3 returns 265 results (0.004 sec)

And I am completely lost, because `NOT IN` works just fine in other combinations and I just can't see the difference.

**Update:** Okay, it is a duplicate :D . To my defense - the actual original has a very nondescript name ;)

Comment: FWIW, your "sanity check" query is the best query anyway because it doesn't use a correlated-subquery which tend to have worse performance.

Comment: I think the problem might be `NULL` values in your `z.username` column and/or `a.mail_username` column (as `NULL` values cause all comparisons to fail).

Comment: @Dai wow, that might be it. I didn't know about the NULL thing. thanks! :)